# Having launched X, can I shutdown without a mouse?

Tags: xorg, keyboard, mouse

I've launched into X using `startx`, but now can't shutdown my pi, as I have no mouse, and I can't seem to access anything with the keyboard alone. What can I do?

Comment: Which OS do you have?

Comment: @finnw The recommended Debian

Comment: Try making a button adapting this tutorial http://www.repairhub.co.uk/content/resources/raspberry-pi-battery-backup

Comment: Have you tried unplugging it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

This will switch you to a different tty.
After logging in on this you can run commands 
as normal

Any <kbd>F</kbd> key under 6 will do.

Comment: This switched out to the console running X, I could then terminate X with `ctrl-c` and shutdown the machine.

Comment: @TomMedley Glad I could help.

Comment: This is a bit of a `sledge hammer` solution I think.

Comment: @Skizz It's the only solution that will work in any session.

Comment: I'd be surprised if the system key or alt didn't work, but I haven't tried this.

Answer (score 6):

Why not stop it with `sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop`

Comment: I doubt that that would be possible, unless there was a terminal window open, and currently focused when the mouse was removed.

Comment: If there is no window manager, decorator, etc. it means that `startx` didn't launch `lightdm`. Then `lightdm` status is not set as `started/running` and thus it can't be stopped with `sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop`

Answer (score 4):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

This will kill the running X server.

Comment: This doesn't work by default on recent versions of X.

Comment: I wasn't sure to be honest!

Comment: No harm done. It's still useful to know. Some Window Managers re-enable it.

Comment: @Jivings If I remember correctly, raspi-config actually allows to enable it.

Answer (score 4):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> brings up the 'start' menu (for want of a better word) and then you can use the arrow keys to select 'logout'.

Which is the same as Windows - if you've not got a <kbd>Windows</kbd> key then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> does the same thing (OK, a bit off topic but thought I'd make sure everyone understood I wasn't just thinking it was Windows and that it also works on the default Pi desktop).

Comment: However, this is dependant on the display manager, whereas my solution will work in any X session.

Answer (score 1):

If `sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop` works, then make bash script in `/bin`:

```
$ cd /bin
$ sudo nano stopx
```

In the new file insert the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop
```

save and exit nano, i.e.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Make the file executable:

```
$ chmod +x stopx
```

Finally one may use `stopx` as opposite of `startx`!